# Bootstrap Date & Time Picker not working locally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tiered running bootstrap date & time picker locally by creating an html file but it doesn't worked although its working fine when i pasted the code in JSFiddle (link : https://jsfiddle.net/fuu1v2t0/10/).

```js
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      pick12HourFormat: true
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
    <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I  included these files for the same.
    bootstrap.min.js,
    bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js,
    bootstrap-combined.min.css,
    bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css,
    bootstrap.css,

Comment: Do you include jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here works with jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="well">
  <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
    <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text"></input>
    <span class="add-on">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
      </i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reason it worked in fiddle even  though you didn't include jQuery is:

[image]

Click on javascript settings tab and you will see jQuery is already there.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have called jQuery files also.

```
"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
```

could mean that you don't have the jQuery libraries called in the page.

Try adding this script link to your header. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery in the head tag:

Code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
```

:)